# How can i merge array in ezpublish template?

Tags: php, ezpublish

If any one could help me to add arrays in ez publish.

i have arrays link

```
{def $a = array(a,b,c)}
{def $b = array(d,e)}
```

i want an output in an array like

```
$c = array(a,b,c,d,e);
```

Comment: sorry fren array_merge function is not available in ezpublish templating. it an php function

Comment: you can run foreach() on 2 array and build new one ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will surely work:

```
{def $c = merge($a,$b)}
```

output:
array(a,b,c,d,e)